# Microsoft app publishing error while updating the existing application

Tags: flutter, microsoft-store

I am trying to publish update of my application on microsoft store. when i try to update the package i am recieving this error:

> All .msix and .appx packages (including previously published and currently uploaded) must be uniquely identified by their full names. You have provided two packages with the full name 41052CodersBay.Lodgex_1.0.0.0_X64_ which have different contents. Please remove one of these packages, or increment current package versions to continue.

i tried to change the msix configuration in my **pubsec.yaml** file. i changed the version and rebuilt the msix but it still gave me the same error while updating. this is my msix configuration:
msix_config:
display_name: LODGEX
publisher_display_name: Coders Bay
publisher: hidden
identity_name: hidden
capabilities: "internetClient"
logo_path: D:\APPS\eaziprep_app_desktop\assets\logo1.png
version: 2.0.1.0

i tried to find solutions on microsoft forum but couldn't resolve my issue.I want to know alternative methods to solve this error.

**Moreover,** is there anyway i can delete my application from microsoft store?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to it. it was quite easy. i just had to change the version of my app in pubsec.yaml file instead of msix configuration.

> name: eaziprep_app_desktop description: "Eaziprep Desktop App"
> **version: 2.0.0+1**

i just changed this version from 1.0.0+1 to 2.0.0+1 and it solved the problem and app got updated successfully